# Modal does not let me show alerts

Tags: jquery, modal-dialog

I am using a jQuery Modal popup script. It can be downloaded from:
[Modal Popup](http://deseloper.org/downloads/examples/simple-modal-redux/simple-modal-redux.zip)

I did come across an issue while using this script. I am using the modal window to show a contact form. Now within this modal window contact form, I have attached the following event to the form:

```
<form id="frm_contact" name="frm_contact" method="post" action="index.php" onsubmit=”return validateform(this);”>
```

So what I am trying to do is, validating the input upon clicking the submit button/form submission. An extract from this JS is following:

```
function validateform(frm_contact)
{
  alert(‘hi’);
  return false;
}
```

As you can see, I expected the ‘hi’ to popup but that never happened. This means that no alerts would be shown for any of the input fields upon validation. So in short, I am unable to show alerts within this modal window. How can I fix it so that I can show the alerts?

Comment: Well, modal is modal. Modal dialogs block everything else. What did you expect?

Comment: Seems strange that an alert is not shown because of the modal plugin. Are u sure the code actually executes ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Which browser are you using? Are you certain `validateform` is being called, is it visible in scope from the document containing`form`?

Comment: Thank you so much. I reviewed the code and found out that I did a very, very, veryyy simple mistake. While I was copying the code, I place the Submit button outside of the form & no wonder, the JS was not triggered. I now placed the button in the form & it works perfectly. So thank you for the prompt reply.

Answer (score 0):

```
<form id="frm_contact" name="frm_contact" method="post" action="index.php" onsubmit=”return validateform(this);”>
```

Try to fix with double quote "".

```
onsubmit=”return validateform(this);”
```

to

```
onsubmit="return validateform(this);"
```

Comment: Thanks for the efforts, but that is not the correct solution. I have posted the solution in reply to "Lloyd's" comment above.